# Is it possible to use JMH with JDK 17?

Tags: java, maven, jmh, java-17

Currently using trying to use JMH 1.33 with JDK 17. However, invoking JMH programatically seems to use sun.mis.Unsafe. Since 1.33 is the latest version of JMH, it therefore seems like it is impossible to use JMH with JDK 17? I hope this is not the case since I'm trying to benchmark some of the newer APIs so using an older version of the JDK is not an option for me.

I'm using the following wrapper code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(QuadPointBenchmark.class.getName())
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(10))
                .detectJvmArgs()
                .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
```

And here are the relevant portions of my pom file:

```xml
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jmh.version>1.33</jmh.version>
        <javac.target>17</javac.target>
        <uberjar.name>benchmarks</uberjar.name>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you try? Java 17 doesn't disallow to use sun.misc.Unsafe. The only thing that could get in your way  is if the JMH code uses an Unsafe method that has been removed in 17.

Comment: The comment that "Java 17 doesn't disallow to use sun.misc.Unsafe" is not correct, where are getting this information from?

Comment: @AlanBateman I meant it in the sense of "*Strongly encapsulate all internal elements of the JDK, except for critical internal APIs such as sun.misc.Unsafe*" in JEPs 260, 396, 403 which all make an exemption for Unsafe.

Comment: I should perhaps have said *doesn't make it impossible* instead of *doesn't disallow*. Of course, using internal APIs was frowned upon even in Java 1.0